# z-index issue in the message for previously suspended users

Tags: bug, design, moderator-election

I  am trying to get into the meta post of candidate's answers from the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). at the bottom, I am able to find 2 links and so I clicked on the **nominate yourself as a candidate** link.

It take me a page to nominate myself but since I got a suspension in February,

I saw a message.

[image]

> z-index of the overlay (div.lightbox) is **8950**.
>
> z-index of the message (div.message) is **1001**.

Clicking anywhere in the overlay even in message box suspend the message box and overlay and the click action not take place (even if it was in a button or link in the message).

also the position is from center to right. not exactly center positioned

Comment: Went to see if I could reproduce but then I saw I don't satisfy the needs to nominate myself. Now I made myself sad.

Comment: @Albzi any good standing 3k+ user can nominate.

Comment: Providing you have the badges that you need to! I am missing the `Convention` badge, as I am more of a lurker/commenter on Meta rather than a poster. So I cannot nominate myself because of that.

Comment: Additionally you need 4 badges as described in [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) besides having good standing.

Comment: I didn't noticed that. I just checked your rep only. I failed in another crieteria. _suspension_ Thanks to my colleague